# Legendary Retribution: Story or All Heroes?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

There's an achievement for completing Retribution on Legendary, but does it matter if you finish the All Heroes version or the Story version on Legendary? Do you get the achievement regardless of which one you finish? Also, different but related question: does it matter on which version you manage to finish the mission without having any of your teammates downed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All achievements require you to be playing Story mode, unless it specifically mentions you have to be playing All Heroes mode.

Comment: Well, damn, that makes it a lot harder. Good thing I didn't waste my time with it, then. Thanks!